# How to find only the first smallest integer in a list

Tags: python

I have find a smallest element on a list and return a new list without the smallest element. That should be easy with min() but I have to remove only the first occurrence of that integer so [1, 4, 1, 2] would turn into [4, 1, 2]. When I try min() it removes all occurrences of a smallest integer. Is there a way to do it with min() or do I have to look for another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    if v == min(my_list):
        my_list.pop(i)
        break
```

Even better:

```py
my_list.pop(my_list.index(min(my_list)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `remove` method will remove the first occurrence of an item.

```
lst = [1, 4, 1, 2]
lst.remove(min(lst))
print(lst)
```

gives

```
[4, 1, 2]
```

As can be seen from the above, `remove` does an in-place modification to the list, so if you don't want to modify the original list then start by making a copy (using e.g. `new_list = lst.copy()`) and work on the copy.  Note that the same is also true of the `pop` method mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Good answer - `remove()` is one of those useful functions I always seem to forget.